# What does feeling strongly mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-construction

I found the following statement [here in one of the comments on the accepted answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/31460/optimizing-bubble-sort-code): "You feel so strongly about bubble sort that you did not even read the code." Is it correct to say "feel so strongly"? I mean... feel what? I would have said "You hate bubble sort so strongly that..." Is my version correct? Is his version correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You feel so strongly about bubble sort that you did not even read the
>   code.

This sentence works. However, in this sentence we are not given any specific information about the feeling other than that it is strong. This is a commonly used way of expressing that there do exist strong feelings but it is vague. The vagueness partly helps to keep the sentence from become too direct or rude. Think of it as a way of slightly softening the expression.

> You hate bubble sort so strongly that...

This also works. In this example, we are stating specifically that the emotions are ones of hatred. It is more direct, and sounds very strong.